# Exchange ews api, list all users

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am trying to retrieve all users of an exchange server using EWS API, as [this answer](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/a29ba25e-3d37-462a-827b-7e5d1ddb099f/get-users-list-from-exchange-server-using-ews-api) suggested, it's possible to do with powershell. However, I will need perform this task to many servers, running the script in each server is very time consuming, configuring remote EMC seemed not easy either.

So, I am thinking of implement this with C#, looping through each server and retrieve user list and save it in a database. But I couldn't find the EWS equivalent to "***Get-Mailbox***"
powershell command?

What should I do with this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell cmdlets with C# applications. There is a short example of using cmdlets with Exchange in the [Exchange Management Shell SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/ff326155%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Chuck, but I am not a big fan of  putting magic strings in c# code. So, I will try different approach.